# Await reply in private message discord.js

Tags: javascript, database, async-await, private, discord.js

So, this works ALMOST as intended. I have the bot private messaging the user who uses the correct command in the correct channel of the server. Instead of clogging up the server with profile creation messages, I have the bot do profile creation privately. I know/think the problem is with the message.channel.awaitMessages, because it only sees the replies in the original channel on the server where the command was put into place.

I am not sure what I should replace the message.channel.awaitMessages with in order for it to pick up on the reply in the private message conversation rather than the original profile creation channel on the server.

I have not tested the sql message yet. I haven't tested what I have but I am pretty sure it won't work. I want the reply that is given by the user in the private message to be inserted (updated maybe?) into a mysql database I have already set up and properly got working. The users ID and username has been put into this table with the rest of the profile related questions being null at this moment. As they reply to these questions, those fields can be filled out/updated. Any ideas/suggestions are welcome!

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
if(message.channel.id === '460633878244229120') return message.author.send(`Greetings, ${message.author.username}! FIRST QUESTION, **What is the name of your Brawler or Character?**`)
  .then(function(){
    message.channel.awaitMessages(response => message.content, {
      max: 1,
      time: 5000,
      errors: ['time'],
    })
    .then((collected) => {
        message.author.send(`Your Name is: ${collected.first().content}`);
        var sql = (`UPDATE profile SET name = '${message.content}' WHERE id = ${message.author.id}`);
      })
      .catch(function(){
        message.author.send('Please submit a name for your character. To restart Profile creation, please type "!profilecreate" command in Profile Creation channel on the server.');
      });
    });
  }
```

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use SQL so, since the question is not specifically on that, don't ask me.

When you're using `message.channel.awaitMessages`, `message` is still the first one that you passed in the `module.exports.run` function, not the one that comes from `send()`. When `send` is resolved, it passes a new message, that you have to include in the arguments of the function you put inside `then`: so, instead of `.then(function() {})` you'll need something like `.then(function(new_message_sent_in_private) {})`

This should fix the problem:

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
if(message.channel.id === '460633878244229120') return message.author.send(`Greetings, ${message.author.username}! FIRST QUESTION, **What is the name of your Brawler or Character?**`)
  .then((newmsg) => { //Now newmsg is the message you sent
    newmsg.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content, {
      max: 1,
      time: 5000,
      errors: ['time'],
    }).then((collected) => {
      newmsg.channel.send(`Your Name is: ${collected.first().content}`);
      var sql = (`UPDATE profile SET name = '${message.content}' WHERE id = ${message.author.id}`);
    }).catch(() => {
      newmsg.channel.send('Please submit a name for your character. To restart Profile creation, please type "!profilecreate" command in Profile Creation channel on the server.');
    });
  });
}
```

Let me now if that worked :)

Comment: Yes, that did work. However, the mysql isn't working, which is what I expected. I'll figure it out! Thanks for your help because this seems to be working great! :)