# awaitMessages inside async function discord.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, discord

I am fairly new to async and I am trying to get the response from a user to a bot via a private message. I have done this before in sync, but not async. I have working code that properly awaits reactions that I worked into the following code, but it doesn't seem to work the same way (obviously) as I am getting `(node:10080) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: msg.awaitMessages is not a function` as an error when I run it.

I've looked around in trying to find awaitMessages to work for a private message inside an async function but it looks to be more complicated than putting something like the answer to this question [Await reply in private message discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116013/await-reply-in-private-message-discord-js)

```
async function cardExists() {
let matchedcards = []

let msg = await message.author.send(`Please provide the cardnames that you would like to add to '${userdeckname}'.\n\n**NOTE:** Please separate each card with a comma and space, like so "Pact of Darkness, Aquos Slam, Karmic Balance"`)

const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
const reply = await msg.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1 })
.catch(console.error);

let cardsToAdd = reply.first()

let usercardnamearray = cardsToAdd.content.split(", ")
```

I simply want the question to be asked, and await the user to reply in a private message to the discord bot. Some code that runs after the snippet above (once cardsToAdd is declared) ends up checking if each card in the list exists in a mysql database and pushes the cards that succeed to an array to be used later and sends the cards that fail to the private chat.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, but It looks like you should use `msg.channel.awaitMessages` instead of `msg.awaitMessages` https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages

Comment: Hm... I figured since it was a private message, there wasn't a "channel" to send it to. I guess that solved the problem. I feel like an idiot. Thank you! XD If you want to post it as an answer instead of a comment, I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `msg.channel.awaitMessages` instead of `msg.awaitMessages` according to the [official documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages).